# Writing to a mac csv not working using python file writter

Tags: python, macos, csv, line-breaks, file-writing

I have a python code where it compares two files and returns the common lines and writes them to a result file. I am using a MAC machine.

script.py

```
with open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with open('serialnumbers.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
        print same

with open('results.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
        print line
```

temp1.csv

```
M11435TDS144
M11543TH4292
SN005
M11509TD9937
M11543TH4258
SN005
SN006
SN007
```

serialnumbers.txt

```
G1A114042400571
M11251TH1230
M11543TH4258
M11435TDS144
M11543TH4292
M11509TD9937
```

The output of the above script on mac is

> set([])

If I run the same script on windows it is working fine. I found out that this is a csv problem on mac. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If it is a CSV file on Windows, it use "\r\n" delimiters. I make the assumption that one file has "\r\n" and the other only "\n". Can you check that?

Comment: tested on a mac and got different output than the one you describe ...

Comment: Try: `same = set(l.strip() for l in file1).intersection(l.strip() for l in file2)`

Comment: can you please add one extra new line on each of temp and serialnumber files and please test it again -Thank you

Comment: which python version is this ?

Comment: @Soundararajan python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

The end delimiters of the two files are different.

- The .csv file probably has Windows end of line: "\r\n",
- The .txt file probably has Posix end of line: "\n".

So, in binary mode, lines always differ.

You ought to read the two files in text mode, like this:

```
import io

with io.open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with io.open('serialnumbers.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
        print(same)
```

You'll get:

```
set([u'M11543TH4258\n', u'M11509TD9937\n', u'M11543TH4292\n', u'M11435TDS144\n'])
```

Also notice that CSV files are usually encoded using ISO-8859-1 or cp1252 encoding (legacy encoding from Windows).

#### to drop the newlines

```
with io.open('temp1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    with io.open('serialnumbers.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(line.strip() for line in file1).intersection(line.strip() for line in file2)
        print(same)
```

Comment: Then you will need to *reappend* the new line characters for consistency.

Comment: Thank you laurent.. This helped..But when I am writing that to a result file it is writing all as a same line.

Comment: @KrishnaPrasad: So use the first solution: don't strip the lines…